# How to automatically include formulas in specific column when an excel workbook is opened?

Tags: excel, vba, alteryx

I have an excel workbook which I am creating with the help of Alteryx. Alteryx populates the cells with values instead of formulas. Now when I open the workbook, I want just one of the columns in Sheet 1 to be populated with formulas (not just pasted values from alteryx). How do I do that using MACROS?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should try [Worksheet.Activate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.activate(even))

Comment: Automatically run a macro when the workbook is openen. For more info see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with the event "Workbook_Open".
the below code will insert when you open the workbook, the formula `=SUM(D2,E2)` in column A from row 1 to 20

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim CheckRange As Range
Dim x As Range

Set CheckRange = Range("A1:A20")

For Each x In CheckRange
    x.Formula = "=SUM(D2,E2)"
Next

End Sub
```